# password key question

Tags: password, samba

Sorry this is a vague question just now but I feel I need to ask it and "get things going" rather than wait for next time as I will (again) get flustered by/with it.

I have an SSH key with password for any SSH logging I do.

Recently I bought a NVIDIA shield and it allows SMB access to it.

I open a `file explorer` and navigate to it.
I am then asked for the username and password which I enter.

I have 3 options at this stage:  Don't remember login, remember login for this time, remember login always.

I pick the third one and am prompted to enter my "key password".
If I enter the password for the SSH login, it doesn't accept it.

I don't/didn't know I had such a file or to what it is referring.

Just now I am logged in and doing things.  I know a reboot may not be a big thing in the scheme of things.  But I have a handful of other things happening and I would prefer to not have to restart the machine and get the actual happenings.

Yes, ok, that is a bit slack of me as I am the one asking the question.
I'm hoping someone may get what I man from just this and explain the problem.

If not: next time I boot up and go through that I will try to remember to get that missing information.

Thanks in advance.
(I hope)

Ok, things happened and I am back.
This is the screen I see when I try to save the log in details

[image: This is the prompt I don't understand]

Comment: do you use automatic login?  if so, then your keyring doesn't get unlocked because there was no password prompt, so use your user password at that page.

Comment: There is a log in page and I enter the required details.
I didn't think to screen shot that screen.
I shall try to remember to do that next time.
But I am confused to the "login keyring" that is mentioned on that screen shot.

Comment: You probly forgot the passwd. If not just enter the correct passwd. Or start with a new login keyring by deleting the old one and making a new one with "seahorse". Or just delete or rename ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring.